# VBA Class() buliding same object class structur in excel as in outlook

Tags: vba, class, properties, get

what I want to achieve is to build the same class structer as I have in Outlook. Means:
sFilename = item.Attachments.item(i).Filename '"myTFile.txt"

I have written code in Outlook. I cannot change and test while Outlook is running so I try to write the code upfront in Excel and I try to build the class structur the same as in outlook that I don´t have to change the code afterwards, so for instance:

```
sFileName = item.Attachments.item(i).Filename
```

I tried with Properties Get in that way:
Building classes: 
clsMail with content:

```
Property Get item() As clsItem
    Set item = New clsItem
End Property
```

clsItem with content:

```
Property Get Sender() As String
  sFileName = "myFile.txt"
  Dim objFSO As Object: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If objFSO.FileExists(sFileName) Then
    Dim objShell As Object, objFolder As Object, objFolderItem As Object
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application"): Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(sPathEDIportalLogs)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("myFile.txt")
    Sender = Split(objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 10), "\")(1)
  End If
End Property

Property Get ReceivedTime() As Date
    ReceivedTime = Date
End Property

Property Get Subject() As String
    Subject = "Subject Text"
End Property

Property Get Attachments() As clsAttachments
    Set Attachments = New clsAttachments
End Property
```

So far so good till `item.Attachments`
But now I am struggeling with the rest `item(i).Filename`
Again `item` and as array. I tried a lot but get it not done.
Who can help.

I'm hitting an *out of stack space* error:

[image: what I got so far with debugging]

Comment: A `Property Get` member should have exactly 0 chances of throwing an error. That `Sender` property should be a `Function`, and its name should start with a verb. Now, that *out of stack space* error is because you've accidentally made this `item` property *recursive*, i.e. it's calling itself, and VBA will only go to a certain depth before it gives up. Assigning the return value of a property/function is done using the identifier of that property/function, so `item = sPathEDIportalLogs & "myFile.txt"`. That `(0)` is what's causing the recursive call.

Comment: @Mathieu, thanks for answering. But how can I leave my "outlook" code untouched in excel? What needs to be done to get results for  item.Attachments.item(0).Filename or item.Attachments.Count. What is the secured way to get that? cheers Asterios

Answer (score 1):

**You're recursing. Infinitely.**

item(0) is calling into your getter. 
which is accessing item(0). 
which is calling into your getter.
which is accessing item(0).

**Sort-of-unrelated, but very important side note:** Accessing a getter should NEVER change anything. It's a horrible code practice. It'll shoot you in the foot more than you'll ever imagine.

Don't do it.. :)